# $f(x)=x^a$ Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, area

Consider $f(x)=x^a $

Now $\int_0^1 x^a = 1/(1+a)$ gives the area bounded by the function, $x $ axis, $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Now consider $a<-1$

On LHS the function is positive for all $0<x<1$

Still the area bounded by the function comes out to be negative? How?

This formula is given in my book and is proved by considering that differentiation of $\frac {x^{1+a}}{a+1} $ is $ x^a $

What am I doing wrong?

Please Explain.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. The integral itself becomes infinite and the formula invalid at $a=-1$, and whole the formula makes sense for lower $a$,  the integral never makes it "back down" to finite value.

Answer (score 4):

For $\;a<-1\;$ as you want, the function $\;x^a\;$ isn't defined  at $\;x=0\;$ nor bounded on a right nieghborhood of zero, and then integral $\;\int_0^1 x^a\;dx\;$ becomes an improper non-convergent integral

Comment: Note that it is improper already for $a<0$, but for $-1<a<0$ it is _convergent_.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, I know. That's why I wrote "improper non-convergent".

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Comment: Thank you very much, @Dr.MV

Comment: I see, @Arthur . Thank you.

Comment: Thanks.
 I get it, as $a$ tends to $-1$ the area tends to infinity and for further $a<-1$ it becomes meaningless. 

In my book this formula is given for indefinite integrals and is proved by considering differentiation as a reverse process of integration and they have only given one condition i.e a should not be equal to -1. 
For indefinite integrals, do we keep using this for any a not equal to -1?

Comment: @BelalAhmed In general, for *any* $\;a\neq-1\;$ , we have $$\int_0^1x^a=\left.\frac1{a+1}x^{a+1}\right|_0^1=\frac1{a+1}\left(1-\lim_{b\to0^+}b^{a+1}\right)$$But the above limit doesn't exist finitely if $\;a+1<0\iff a<-1\;$, and that is why your integral diverges in this case. For $\;-1<a<0\;$ , the integral *still is* improper, but it converges since $$-1<a<0\iff a+1>0\implies\lim_{b\to0^+}b^{a+1}=0$$ For $\;a=-1\;$ we get a logarithmic divergent integral, too.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$\int_0^1 x^adx=\frac{1}{1+a}$$
is based on the assumption that $a>-1$. Otherwise, the integral diverges,
$$\int_0^1x^adx=\infty,\quad\text{for }a\leq -1.$$